# StringLength Mvc

Tags: model-view-controller, properties

As you know there is a property called `[StringLength]` in model of mvc. I have a variable which is an `int` and I want to restrict it to maximum 4 characters. I need something like `[IntLength]`. Can you help me?

```
[Display(Name="Credit card number:")]
[RegularExpression(@"\d{4}")]
public int BookingCardNumberFirstFour { get; set; }

<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BookingCardNumberFirstFour, new {style="width:40px;"}) %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the range attribute.

```
[Range(0,9999)]
public int myInt { get; set;}
```

if you want them to enter exactly 4 digits use the regular expression attribute.

```
[RegularExpression(@"\d{4}")]
public int myInt {get; set;}

<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.BookingCardNumberFirstFour, new {style="width:40px;"}) %>
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BookingCardNumberFirstFour) %>
```

Comment: @Ktt Can you post what you tried? Are you getting any errors? please provide more detail.

Comment: [Display(Name = " Credit Card Number:")]
        [Range(4, 4)]
        public int BookingCardNumberFirstFour { get; set; }

Comment: I dont get any error but it doesnt work. I am compling it again and again but nothing happens

Comment: @Ktt i've modified my answer to include another attribute. please try it out and let me know. Do you want a max of 4 characters or the person must enter 4 characters?

Comment: I need to get the credit card numbers from the user so it is int variable but I have to maxlenght it. It is quite simple but it didnt work

Comment: @Ktt try out the regular expression attribute i just added. it will work.

Comment: @Ktt could you post some parts of the model as part of you question? Just edit you question a bit to include parts of the model.

Comment: the model doesnt contain anything else. I added the html part as well.

Comment: The person has to enter max and min 4 characters